# Waveforms of BLDC motor

Tags: motor, oscilloscope, brushless-dc-motor, waveform

I am using L6235 to drive a BLDC motor with hall sensors, but I am not sure about the motor's wire connection. Can you tell which connection is correct by looking at the waveforms?

datasheet of L6235: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6235.pdf

Below are the waveforms captured at the output pin, are the waveforms correct?
[image: channel 1: voltage, channel 2: current]

(channel 1: voltage, channel 2: current)

However, if I swap 2 of the phase, the motor is still rotating and the IC gets really hot. Why is it like that? And I got some waveforms:

[image: channel 1: pin OUT1, channel 2: pin OUT2]

(channel 1: pin OUT1, channel 2: pin OUT2)

[image: channel 1: pin H1, channel 2: pin OUT1]

(channel 1: pin H1, channel 2: pin OUT1)

Comment: Correct with what kind of measure?

Answer (score 1):

The waveform on the first picture is correct.  The hall effect devices are used to provide the timing to switch phases.  You cannot swap phases without changing the halls; otherwise the motor phases will switch at the wrong time, and the direction of the motor rotor's torque change to the wrong direction when the hall signal change.  The motor is working against itself and current limiting because of this.

Comment: The voltage looks fine, but the current seems strange. Could it be because of a heavy load, or is it normal? I ask because the few I've seen looked fairly well sinusoidal.

Comment: The current ripple is due to a mismatch between the motor's back EMF and the trapezoidal waveform you are supplying.  This is always going to be present.  If you do PWM, there are PWM techniques you can use to reduce this.